# I can't get OpenCV library to work in PyCharm, returns "Cannot find reference 'imread' in '__init__.py'" and more errors

Tags: python, pycharm

After importing cv2 in Pycharm, every function associated with cv2 returns an error for some reason. [list of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xVEe.png). I have already gone through countless posts on Stack Overflow but none of the suggested answers have helped.

Here is the code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

# Read the image
image = cv.imread('image')

# Convert the image to grayscale
gray = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Blur the image to reduce high frequency noise
blurred = cv.GaussianBlur(gray, (9, 9), 0)

# Threshold the image to create a binary image
threshold, thresh_image = cv.threshold(blurred, 50, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY)

# Dilate the image to fill in the holes
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
dilated = cv.dilate(thresh_image, kernel, iterations=2)

# Invert the image to create a mask
mask = cv.bitwise_not(dilated)

# Apply the mask to the original image
result = cv.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)

# Save the resulting image
cv.imwrite('image_without_stars.jpg2', result)
```

Here is what I have tried:

- updating PyCharm to version (3.11)
- changing the location of 'image'
- adding the directory where the Python interpreter is installed to the PATH environment variable
- re-downloading OpenCV library
- copying the code to notepad, saving it and trying to execute that file in the terminal
- copying the cv2 file from the cv2 folder into the site-packages folder (because another post on this site said to try it)

It is also possible that I didn't do some of these things correctly...

Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this?

Comment: try to install cv2 using pycharm package manager.

Comment: also, make sure you don't have a file named cv2.py, as it will conflict with importing correctly.